# How to Enable Ascending or Descending In WordPress Default Built-in Loop

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, loop

Can someone please let me know how we can add Order functionality to WordPress Built-in Loop?

```
<?php 
if (have_posts()) { 
    while (have_posts()) { 
        the_post(); 
        // Post Content here 
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```

I know this is doable in `WP_Query` like

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

but how we can do this is default loop?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`parse_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_query/) hook to override the default main query:

```php
add_action( 'parse_query', function ( WP_Query $wp_query ) {
    /**
     * Only apply our custom ordering when:
     * - We're not in the admin
     * - It's an archive (i.e. not singular)
     * - It's the main query (won't affect custom WP_Query)
     */
    if ( ! is_admin() && ! $wp_query->is_singular() && $wp_query->is_main_query() ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        $wp_query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }
});
```

This needs to live in a plugin or your theme's `functions.php`.